# Why Mail option is not available when sharing Image in Windows 8 application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Am trying to `share an Image` via `Share charm`, but in the charm '`Mail`' application not available so that couldn't share image through mail . But i tried to share the same image via `Native Photo app` & there `Mail` option available.

[image: my app: share view]
[image: Native Photo app :Share view]

Below my code

```
    private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = e.Request.GetDeferral();

    DataPackage requestData = e.Request.Data;
    requestData.Properties.Title = "Image";
    IRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    Guid encoderId;
    switch (file.FileType)
    {
        case ".png":
            encoderId = BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId;
            break;
        case ".jpg":
        case ".jpeg":
        default:
            encoderId = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId;
            break;
    }
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, stream);
    Stream pixelStream = image.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
    await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)image.PixelWidth, (uint)image.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
    requestData.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream));
    await encoder.FlushAsync();

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Am i missed anything there in my code?

-------------------------------------EDIT---------

Got an alternative ; see this [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6e003421-e78d-4213-87a2-fc4a96cc4070/why-mail-option-is-not-available-when-sharing-image-in-windows-8-application?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [sharing content source app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84)? It's saying...

> It's recommended to use both SetBitmap and SetStorageItems for sharing
>   a single image since the target app may only support one or the other.

So if you use only `SetBitmap(...)`, Mail app won't recognize. You need to create image file temporary folder and then use `SetStorageItems(...)`

Comment: yea. i managed to save image to local before sharing it . Now Mail sharing option is available. :)